# What does it mean when Rust throws the error "cannot move out of `*variable` which is behind a shared reference"?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and I have this code while following a tutorial. All that this set of code does is loop through the numbers and add up the total.

```
enum Shot {
    Bullseye,
    Hit(f64),
    Miss,
}

impl Shot {
    fn points(self) -> i32 {
        match self {
            Shot::Bullseye => 5,
            Shot::Hit(x) if x < 3.0 => 2,
            Shot::Hit(x) => 1,
            _ => 0,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut shots: Vec<Shot> = Vec::new();

    shots.push(Shot::Bullseye);
    shots.push(Shot::Hit(5.0));
    shots.push(Shot::Miss);

    let mut total = 0;

    for shot in shots.iter() {
        let points = shot.points();
        total += points
    }

    println!("Total: {}", total);
}
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*shot` which is behind a shared reference
   |
68 |         let points = shot.points();
   |                      ^^^^^--------
   |                      |    |
   |                      |    `*shot` moved due to this method call
   |                      move occurs because `*shot` has type `Shot`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `*shot`
  --> src/main.rs:21:15
   |
21 |     fn points(self) -> i32 {
   |               ^^^^
```

Strangely, if I change it to this, everything compiles without error:

```
    for shot in shots {
        let points = shot.points();
        total += points
    }
```

Why does it work when I remove the iterator? And yet the loop works without the iterator?

I tried deciphering the error message but still couldn't understand what is happening. In this case, I believe `shot` is a reference. I'm calling the `shot.points()` function which returns an `i32` value which is owned by the variable `points`. Yet, the error mentioned about `shot` being moved due to the call on the `shot.points()` function?

What does the error really mean and why is that happening?

Comment: You don't want your `points()` method to take `self`, because then it consumes the value it receives, and there's no reason to do that (here). Have it take `&self` instead, and things will work.

Comment: And without `.iter()` your very iteration is consuming the `shots` vector (which you'd discover if you tried using it afterwards), so individual calls to `points()` work on actual owned values, for which it's fine that `points()` consumes it - because it will never be used again anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try and get the actual type of `shot` inside the loop:

```
for shot in shots.iter() {
    let foo: () = shot;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c6d60dea4ff884bc351bfc894cf3a414)

The error message tells us that `shot` has type `&Shot`. In other words, it's a shared reference to `Shot`. But `points` is defined as `fn points (self) -> i32` which means that it expects an owned value, so you can't call `shot.points()` on a reference. As pointed out by others the fix is easy: simply change `points` to take a reference, i.e. `fn points (&self) -> i32` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2d364010604eb6fc5ad2cf3a2f5467fd)).

Now why does it work if we remove the `.iter()`? Look what happens to the type in that case:

```
for shot in shots {
    let foo: () = shot;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=089f013e2ed09b35a74df785e91e8d16)

Now `shot` has type `Shot`, no reference. This is because `for shot in shots` is actually equivalent to `for shot in shots.into_iter()`, which consumes `shots` and iterates over owned values. The consequence is that you can non longer use it after the loop:

```
for shot in shots {
}
println!("{:?}", shots);
```

doesn't work:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `shots`
  --> src/main.rs:32:22
   |
20 |     let mut shots: Vec<Shot> = Vec::new();
   |         --------- move occurs because `shots` has type `Vec<Shot>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
28 |     for shot in shots {
   |                 ----- `shots` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
...
32 |     println!("{:?}", shots);
   |                      ^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
   |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `shots`
  --> /rustc/d5a82bbd26e1ad8b7401f6a718a9c57c96905483/library/core/src/iter/traits/collect.rs:262:18
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` which comes from the expansion of the macro `println` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider iterating over a slice of the `Vec<Shot>`'s content to avoid moving into the `for` loop
   |
28 |     for shot in &shots {
   |                 +
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `points` takes ownership of `shot`, so on the next iteration it can't do that again.

Giving what you do with `shot` (just reading), you may use an immutable reference to solve the issue:

```
fn points(&self) -> i32 {
```

You would also need to dereference `x`

```
Shot::Hit(x) if *x < 3.0 => 2,
```

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d1689125092c804510be5213ab61643c)